# How do I reset pandas dataframe subset index to default

Tags: python, pandas

I have this example code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'month': [1, 4, 7, 10],
               'year': [2012, 2014, 2013, 2014],
               'sale':[55, 40, 84, 31]})
df.set_index('month', inplace=True)
print(df[( df['sale'] > 40)])
```

which produces:

```
       sale  year
month            
1        55  2012
7        84  2013
```

But I need

```
  month  sale  year
0      1    55  2012
2      7    84  2013
```

where I reset the index to default index.   Is there a way to change the print statement to accomplish this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply take out the line `df.set_index('month', inplace=True)`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'month': [1, 4, 7, 10],
               'year': [2012, 2014, 2013, 2014],
               'sale':[55, 40, 84, 31]})

print(df[( df['sale'] > 40)])

#    month  sale  year
# 0      1    55  2012
# 2      7    84  2013
```

That line explicitly sets the index to the `month` column, which you don't want. You could set it, and then unset it using `df.reset_index()` as suggested by @Abdullah Ahmed Ghaznavi, but it seems like unnecessary work, unless you don't have control over the creation of the dataframe

**Note**: If, as suggested by your question, you *only want to change the printed output* (leaving the original dataframe totally untouched), you can use this print statement with your original process:

```
print(df[( df['sale'] > 40)].reset_index())
```

Comment: Hello.  The df.set_index('month', inplace=True) was added intentionally in order to see how can I add a default index to the df subset, preferably in the print statement

Comment: See my note in my edit, that only modifies the `print` statement

Answer (score 3):

Use `df.reset_index()` for info read [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

**Check this:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'month': [1, 4, 7, 10],
               'year': [2012, 2014, 2013, 2014],
               'sale':[55, 40, 84, 31]})
df.set_index('month', inplace=True) # here you are setting index inplace 
print(df[( df['sale'] > 40)])

df.reset_index(inplace=True)  # here i reset it inplace

print(df[( df['sale'] > 40)]) #updated df
```

**It will give you output like this:**

```
   month  sale  year
0      1    55  2012
2      7    84  2013
```

As your desired output!

Hope this will help you! :)

Comment: OP wants the filtered output without month as index

Comment: @Anon : No he want to reset the index

Comment: yes, but showing only the filtered data. Your solution after the edit is correct.